# Is it true that oxygen has a diffusion rate in air 10,000 times greater than in water?

Tags: aquatic-biology

According to the [Wikipedia page on the design of gills](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gill), oxygen has a diffusion rate in air 10,000 times greater than in water. Is that true?

The WP entry refers to: M.B.V. Roberts, Michael Reiss, Grace Monger (2000). Advanced Biology. London, UK: Nelson. pp. 164–165.

Comment: There's no clear biological scope in this question, although a good answer has already been posted.

Comment: I've slightly rewritten the question to make it clear that the OP was coming at this from a biological perspective. (The OP had already linked to the page on gills and cited the Advanced Biology textbook.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, according to calculations presented [here](http://compost.css.cornell.edu/oxygen/oxygen.diff.water.html) and [here](http://compost.css.cornell.edu/oxygen/oxygen.diff.air.html) the conclusion is that:

> The O<sub>2</sub> diffusion coefficient in saturated air (15% oxygen) is 5,700 to 10,800 times greater than in water (60°C and 20°C respectively).

And [here is a paper](http://jeb.biologists.org/content/203/16/2479.full.pdf) using this difference to investigate the transfer of O<sub>2</sub> through the tracheal system of a click beetle.